# Magento 2 All Bundle Product Show Out Of Stock On PDP

Tags: magento2, catalog, bundled-product, inventory

In my magento 2 store show all bundle product OUT OF STOCK.

Comment: Are you doing Migration or Upgrade or another things previously?

Comment: Yes we done Migration .

Comment: it's magento >2.3.x with active MSI modules?

Comment: @RiccardoUgolini Yes MSI modules is enable.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check if in your database there is the view "inventory_stock_1"

[image: inventory_stock_view]

if it is present follow these steps:

- backup the view `inventory_stock_1`
- delete the view `inventory_stock_1`
- run this query

`delete from patch_list where patch_name like '%CreateLegacyStockStatusView%';`

- run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- run `bin/magento indexer:reset`
- run `bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- check the bundle

Cheers

Comment: I try this solution but still not work.